# Ionic alphabetic divider in list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a list in ionic that is coming from a controller, it is a list that gets stored in localStorage I am trying to put alphabetic dividers in the list but I am little confused as to how, the code is:

app.js

```
    $ionicLoading.show({
        template: '<ion-spinner icon="ios"></ion-spinner>',
        hideOnStageChange: true
      });

   $timeout(function () {
      $ionicLoading.hide();
    $scope.myList = [
    'Amazing places',
    'A brief overview',
    'Be my way'
      ];
    }, 2000);

})
```

In view

```
    <ul class="list">
    <li class="item item-checkbox item-text-wrap" ng-repeat='title in myList | filter: search'>
  <label class="checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="localStorage.choice[list]">
  </label>
       <p>{{title}}</p>

    </li>
    <ul>
```

Any ideas on how to get a alphabet divider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the issue https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/ionic-ion-autoListDivider

This directive used in a simple syntax solved it.